# How to run Yii console app from Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, cron

I uploaded my project to a server running Ubuntu. The project has a console command logrotation/index. I want to run it through the command line, and Ubuntu says "yii: command not found". I tried to run it in different ways.
**How to run this console application from the command line and then (for the future) put it as a cronjob?**

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Comment: Please, vote up if like my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside project directory:

```
./yii logrotation/index
```

Or

```
php yii logrotation/index
```

The error message `"yii: command not found"` means that Ubuntu can't find the binary in `$PATH` directories. So you need to specify `./` to show that you are executing a file from the current directory.